# How to count articles in same line

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm working on my site, and I want to make it responsive. I want to center the number of articles in a single line. When there are three displayed inline, the width has to change. I wanted to do it using this script I found:

```
var numofDivs = $("#projects > article").size();
    if (numofDivs = 4){
        var projects = document.getElementById("projects");
        projects.style.backgroundColor="black";
    } else if (numofDivs = 3){
        var projects = document.getElementById("projects");
        projects.style.backgroundColor="grey";
    }
```

but this counts the number of articles in the whole div. I want to count the articles shown in a single line. How do I do this?

Comment: While you are checking your syntax is wrong, you should check with == for exact validation and === for value and type validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole approach is unnecessary. You don't need javascript at all. To center these articles you need to add `text-align: center` to the parent and set `display: inline-block` to the articles themselves. All the CSS you need is:

```
#projects {
    text-align: center;
}
#projects > article {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**One important thing** - if your articles will start to break to the new line, it means you're facing the white-space issue. To fix it, you'll have to leave no space between **closing** tag of each article and **opening** of the next one. Instead of e.g. this:

```html
<article>
    ...
</article>

<article>
    ...
</article>
```

you'll have to do this:

```
<article>
    ...
</article><article>
    ...
</article><article>
    ...
</article>
```

Here's a sample to see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/PsFNF/1/

Comment: Yeaah! Thats what i needed!
i had float:left but that wasnt necessary, it messed the whole thing up.
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood, but maybe you can check the CSS property and then combine it with a sytem to check the width of the window. Anyway I prepared this quick start for you and I hope it can be useful:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>project</title>
<style>
article{ width: 200px; margin:2px; }
.inline{ float:left;}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>
<script>
    $(function(){                                                                                                        

        $("article").each(function(){
            if($(this).css("float")==="left")
                $(this).css("color","steelblue")
            else
                $(this).css("color","gray")
        })

  });
</script>
<body>

<div id="projects">

<article class="inline"><h1>1</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </article>
<article class="inline"><h1>2</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </article>
<article class="inline"><h1>3</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </article>
<article class="inline"><h1>4</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </article>
<article><h1>5</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </article>
<article><h1>6</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </article>
<article><h1>7</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </article>
<article><h1>8</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </article>

</div>
```

Anyway I think that your problem can be re-thought to be resolved with pure css...